# How to pass a Linq staement for another type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

Below I have a method that wraps another method. What I'd like to do is provide an optional parameter to filter the inner method, which is a different type than T.

This is the outside method that is considered the "public" API:

```
public override IQueryable<T> GetEverything()
{
    return Get()
        .Where(i => i.Active == true)
        .Select(i => new T(i));
}
```

As pseudo code, I would like do something like this:

```
var items = GetEverything(x => x.SomeValue > 10);
```

Which would get passed into the method like this

```
   public override IQueryable<T> GetEverything(???)
    {
        return Get()
            .Where(i => i.Active == true)
            .Where(x => x.SomeValue > 10)
            .Select(i => new T(i));
    }
```

Notice I still want to keep my `i.Active` filter and don't want to loose that if the dev decides to pass in a filter. The passed in filter would compound not replace the inner filter. Can anyone help with this? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `??? = Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate` ... `.Where(predicate)`

Comment: try `Predicate<T>` (lambda, compiled code) or `Expression<Predicate<T>>` (abstract code that can be mapped in to sql)

Comment: The above comments are nearly right, just replace `T` with the type of Queryable that `Get()` returns.

Comment: @nsinreal: Unfortunately, while I'd like to suggest using predicates as well, LINQ exclusively uses `Func<T, bool>` - `.Where(...)` won't take a predicate.

Comment: I see, so I added this in the optional parameter like this: Expression<Func<TContent, bool>> filter = null. But if it is null, what happens when .Where(null)?

Comment: @TruMan1 In brief you can do `var x = Get().Where(...); if (filter != null) x = x.Where(filter); return x.Select(...);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the signature of [`Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.100).ASPX):

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
)
```

so in order to pass the parameter to `Where` the simplest way is to require a `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`:

```
public override IQueryable<T> GetEverything(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Get()
        .Where(i => i.Active == true)
        .Where(predicate)
        .Select(i => new T(i));
}
```

Be aware that most query providers have limitations on what expressions can be converted to an underlying store query, so you may run into more run-time errors by providing an open door to the filters.

If you want to keep a single method and allow a `null` predicate you could just chaine the Linq expressions:

```
public override IQueryable<T> GetEverything(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    var query = Get().Where(i => i.Active == true);

    if(predicate != null)
        query = query.Where(predicate);

    return query.Select(i => new T(i));
}
```

Comment: What happens when I do "predicate = null" and it gets passed into the "Where"?

Comment: @TruMan1: I'd suggest use of the language concept known as an `if` in that case, or a different method.

Comment: @Magus I can't see how that's a simple if statement unless I want duplicate code. Notice the Where's must come before the select. Any suggestions on how do to squeeze an if statement between there? Maybe something like this or a better way? .Where(predicate == null || predicate)

Comment: @TruMan1: Every `.` in that statement is a point where you could have a variable. They're only chained to simplify it. You can easily save every step to a variable, and only do a step if some condition is met. You should only need one or two variables, and approximately the same number of lines. Rawling got it right in his comment on your question.